# Apk file is showing corrupted

Tags: android

I am including a share feature in my app to share the app via any intent.
But when it is installed on any other device, the following error pops up
"App not installed. The package appears to be corrupted."
How could I share my app?

Comment: Did you installed the apk using debug mode? if you are trying to install debug mode and then trying to install on some other device then you will face this issue

Comment: 1>delete entire *build folder which is under *app folder.
2>delete all previous apk (for device's guest users too if installed)
3>clean->rebuild->run the app

Comment: do you have instant run enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Use Build>Build APK(s) to build the apk and install the apk directly and then share, it should work.

This is because, from Android Studio 3.0 onwards, the attribute `testOnly` is added to the merged manifest as `android:testOnly="true"`.

This can be verified from Build>Analyze APK>AndroidManifest.xml.

More information can be found [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue go to Build -> Build APK and get the location of apk and run that apk file.It will solve your issue.